# Finding the Jordan Canonical Form of a Classical Adjoint of a Jordan Block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a size $n$ Jordan matrix with $0$ on its diagonal, that is 
$$A = J_n(0) = [a_{ij}] = \begin{cases}
1, &j=i+1\\
0, &\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

What is the Jordan Canonical Form of the classical adjoint of A, $\text{adj} A$?

Can we start with the fact that $A$ is singular and $A (\text{adj} A) = 0_n?$

Comment: If the matrix is in Jordan form and is 0s on its diagonal, the last row of the matrix is all 0 and the matrix is singular, shouldn't it be?

Comment: Are you talking about the adjoint?

Comment: I am talking about A. A has a row that is only 0, the bottom one. Isn't it?

Comment: The first column is zero

Comment: Yup, and the last row as well. Thus $A $ is not non-singular. $A $ is singular

Comment: so how do we construct the jordan canonical form based from this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just start computing the classical adjoint for $n=2,3,4...$ you should notice a pattern as to what they look like.

$$adj\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & - 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$adj\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ adj \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Once you prove that this pattern holds, the Jordan Form is straightforward to compute.

Comment: Oh cool. But dont you think that the adjoint should alternated between 1 and -1 as n varies. Also, I think the only nonzero entry will be in the topright corner, not in the buttom left corner.

Comment: You are right about the sign. The bottom left corner is definitely correct though.

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot to take the transpose! You were right on both counts!

Answer (score 1):

I did  a calculation for the $2\times 2$ block $A$ acting on the $2\times 2$ matrices. We have $\dim \operatorname{ker} \operatorname{adj}(A) = 2$,  $\dim \operatorname{ker} \operatorname{adj}(A)^2 = 3$,$\dim \operatorname{ker} \operatorname{adj}(A)^3 = 4$ ( if $\operatorname{char} k = 0$ then we get $\operatorname{adj}(A)^2= 0$ already).  So in the $2\times 2$  case ($0$ characteristic) we see a Young diagram with columns of size $1$ and $3$.

I think that for characteristic $> n$ or $0$, we have a Young diagram with columns of sizes $1$, $3$, $\ldots$, $2n-1$, and thus Jordan cells of these sizes. I need to get back with more details.

$\bf{Added:}$ The result above is correct. It could be understood as follows.  $A= X$ is part of an $sl2$-[triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sl2-triple), and $X$ acts on $S_{n-1}$ of dimension $n$. Now the action on the $n\times n$ matrices is just $S_{n-1} \otimes S_{n-1}$ which decomposes according to [Clebsch-Gordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients).